# Device that fetches a web API call via wifi showing the result through a display

Tags: wifi, display, website

I would like to build an electronic device that periodically checks some web internet API giving the result through a display.
This device should have:

1. Wireless shield to connect to the internet through some available connection (wep, wpa)
2. LCD display to show the API call results to the user
3. Some way to configure it remotely via http
4. A speaker to alert the user with some rudimental bell sound (Optional)
5. A second LED display to visually alert the user of some new fetched result (Optional)
6. Battery operated (Optional)

I have found [this](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1295621061) project that looks good but does not give any insight about the used components.

I'm just looking for some general input since I'm really a newbie in this field; is this project too complex or is it possible to realize it?
Do you have any suggestion on which components do I need to realize something like this?

Comment: Not battery operated?

Comment: @jpc added as optional requirement

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Microchip Mutimedia Expansion Board](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en548037). It has a

1. Integrated 802.11 module
2. a 3.2 inch QVGA touchscreen
3. Full TCP/IP stack and lots of examples, including GET/POST, SNMP, etc.
4. Headphone and Line out jacks with 24-bit audio codec
5. 5 user-controlled LEDs

It has many other features, but those are the ones you requested. You also need to get a [PIC32 Starter Kit](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2637#hardware). There are 3 types available, a basic (50 dollars US), one with USB (55 dollars US) and one with Ethernet and USB (72 dollars US). They plug into the multimedia board, which is $250.

If you are only building 1, this is probably the easiest route, even if it is over $300.

If you are planning on building lots, then maybe you can get some ideas on how to create your device from this setup.

The Microchip TCP/IP stack is very easy to use and the demo programs they have can be easily modified to do what you are interested in.

Using an Arduino and necessary shields is a good way to go, but this is another option.

Comment: wow, it looks promising.